# My code problem is that when i run the code then list1st elements is automatically copy to the ll node

Tags: java, list, printing, addition, implementation

My code problem is that when i run the code then list1st elements is automatically copy to the ll node

one class for implementation of linked list:

```
public class node {

    static public class Node{
        Node next;
        int data;
        Node(int d)
        {
            this.data=d;
            this.next=null;
        }
        static Node head=null;
        public void add(int data)
        {
             Node new_node = new Node(data); 
                new_node.next = head; 
                head = new_node; 

        }
public void printlist(Node list) {

             Node currNode = list.head; 

                System.out.print("Linked List: "); 

                // Traverse through the Linked List 
                while (currNode != null) { 
                    // Print the data at current node 
                    System.out.print(currNode.data + " "); 

                    // Go to next node 
                    currNode = currNode.next; 
                } 
                System.out.println(" ");
        }
}
}
```

Second class for working on linked list:

```
    public class Linked_list {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Node list1=new Node(0);*// 1st linked list*
            list1.add(10);
            list1.add(1);
            list1.add(15);
            list1.add(3);
            list1.add(88);
            list1.printlist(list1);
            Node ll=new Node(0);   **//second linked list**
            ll.add(55);
            ll.add(44);
            ll.printlist(ll);
        }

 }
```

My code problem is that when i run the code then list1st elements is automatically copy to the ll node.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with your code. The main bug is here in your class `Node`:

```
static Node head=null;
```

The field `head` must not be `static`. Change it to this:

```
private Node head = null;
```

You'll also need to modify the rest of the code to set the `head` variable appropriately: the `add` method should return the newly created `Node` instead of `void`, and in the `main` method you need to use the return value.

Why is it wrong to make it `static`: because `static` makes it a class-level variable, shared by all instances of the class, and that's not what you want.

More info: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Also, the `printlist` method does not need to take a `Node` as an argument. Just make it work on the `Node` you call it on.